# Excel - Remove duplicates and SUM at the same time

Tags: excel, row

I have a column with ID's, but they are duplicated; for instance:

"0,0,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4, ... "

For each row, I have a given value in the other columns, for instance:

"0-24; 0-36; 1-13; 1-34; 1-23;..."

I want to keep only one row with each ID but I need to sum the values of each ID, that is, sum all the values in all columns for a given ID (0,1,2,...), which may include several rows.

Is there a easy way to do this using Excel?

Here is some sample data (table to the left) together with the desired output (tables to the right).

```
ID  Value           ID  Value
0   24              0   60
0   36              1   70
1   13              2   16
1   34              3   24
1   23              4   48
2   16                      
3   9                       
3   15                      
4   24                      
4   24
```

Comment: Programatically or just in general? You could     Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$11").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

Comment: So, you want a table with two columns, one with the ID, the other with the value? e.g. for ID 0, you would have the value of 60? In your original table, is the value next to the 0 really "0-24"? Or is it just "24"?

Comment: yes, I would have a value of "60" for ID "0"; it is just 24. I have several columns, this was just a small example. But my final goal is to obtain, in the "ID" column, a single value for each row, without eliminating information from the other columns!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is to copy your IDs and paste them for example in another Sheet. Let's assume your original table is in Sheet1, and you copy all your IDs to column A in Sheet2.

Then you remove duplicate IDs in Sheet2:

> Select column A > Data Ribbon > Data Tools > Remove Duplicates

In column B, you then put the formula:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!$A:$A, Sheet2!$A2, Sheet1!$B:$B)
```

Note: above formula goes into cell B2 on Sheet2, and you copy it down with `pasteSpecial > only formulas`.

**Edit:** if you still want the same number of rows etc because of the information in your other columns, just skip the "Remove duplicates"-part.

Comment: It seems I completely misunderstood / misinterpreted the question. Thank you for taking the time to correct / revise my edits!

Comment: @Ralph I think you edited it about the same time as she posted her clarifying comment :)