# How to sum excel data in another worksheet, using the value of a reference cell

Tags: excel

I have data in an excel worksheet that is entered daily. I have a column for week number.

In another worksheet I want to have separate rows for each week of data.

I figure I can SUM the daily data into the weekly worksheet using the value in the week number from the first spread sheet.

I can't figure out a simple formula to achieve this? Any attempt to manually enter a SUM formula and drag down, fails as the cells used increases by one rather than 7.

[image]

Comment: Add an example of what you are trying to achieve, struggling to find any real question here.

Comment: It sounds like you need the `Sumif` formula: `SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])`

Comment: How do I add an example of excel data on here? I can add code, but no table option?

Comment: For example with code, and format it with spaces so that it looks like a table. Other option could be a screenshot. About your question, this one is similar in regards to the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856542/excel-remove-duplicates-and-sum-at-the-same-time

Comment: Okay so have added a screenshot of sample data. This is my main worksheet with my 'sessions' data recorded each day. I have another worksheet for weekly. In this I want to SUM all sessions for the corresponding week, e.g. week 23 total, week 24 total etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the second table on Sheet2, and the one you posted is on Sheet1:

`=SUMIF(Sheet1!$B:$B, Sheet2!$A2, Sheet1!$D:$D)`

This formula would go in B2 of Sheet2, if the week numbers are listed in column A, starting in A2.

e.g.:

```
        A        B
1    Week No.   SUM
2      23       5795 
3      24       6204
```